# Pyserial raising Visual c++ runtime error while receiving

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, runtime-error, pyserial

Windows 7 (64 bit), Python 2.7.18 (32 bit)

I have the following class implemented to provide serial communications as part of a larger program:

```
## serial communications thread
class Communication(threading.Thread):
    """
        Serial communications class. Runs in own thread. This class handles
        everything related to interfacing with the serial connection.
    """
    ## thread initialisation
    def __init__(self, port, gui):
        """
            Thread initialisation. Sets up the thread, data queue, state
            variables and connection.
            
            Arguments:
                port (str): The serial port to use.
                gui (ui): Instance of the ui() class which is controlling the
                    GUI.
                    
            No returns.
        """
        global baud
        ## initialise self as a thread
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        
        ## set up local reference to variables from other threads
        self.gui = gui
        
        ## set up a FIFO queue to handle received serial data
        self.rx = Queue.Queue()
        
        ## set up a state variable
        self.terminate = False

        ## actually open the serial connection
        self.lib_serial = gui.serial ## this is 'serial' from the pyserial library. we get this
                                     ## from the gui because it is handling the case
                                     ## where the user forgot to install pyserial
        self.connection = self.lib_serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout = 0.1, write_timeout = 1)

    ## what to do when start() is called on this thread class
    def run (self):
        """
            Main thread loop (runs until terminated). Gets data from the serial
            port, cleans it up and adds it to the receive buffer queue and
            communication log.
            
            No arguments.
            
            No returns.
        """
        ## run forever (in a seperate thread)
        while self.terminate == False:        
            ## read a line of data, with error handling
            try:
                line = self.readline()

                ## strip the endline characters from it
                cleanLine = line.decode("utf-8").rstrip('\r\n')

                ## only proceed if the data isn't a blank line
                if cleanLine != '':
                    ## print out the line
                    self.gui.add_communication(cleanLine, 'rx')
                    self.rx.put_nowait(cleanLine)

            ## if the read didn't succeed
            except:
                print('Error reading from serial connection')

    ## reimplementation of the pyserial readline() function to accept CR or
    ## LF as newline characters. also dumps received data after ten seconds
    def readline(self):
        """
            Reads data until a newline, carrige return or the passage of ten
            seconds of time is seen (whichever is first) and returns it.
            
            No arguments.
            
            Returns:
                (bytes) Data received.
        """
        ## set up a byte array to receive characters
        line = bytearray()
        ## note the start time for timeouts
        start_time = time.time()
        while True:
        
            ## try to get a byte of data
            c = self.connection.read(1)
            ## if there is a byte of data..
            if c:
                ## add it to the line buffer
                line += c
                ## if there is a carrige return (\r) or line-feed (\n)..
                if line[1:] == b'\r' or line[1:] == b'\n':
                    ## break the loop
                    break
            ## if there is no more data available..
            else:
                break
            
            ## if this read has been looping for more than ten seconds, timeout
            ## (but don't raise an error)
            if (time.time() - start_time) > 10:
                break
        
        ## return whatever data we have
        return bytes(line)
                    
    ## write to the serial port one character at a time (to avoid MVME overrun
    ## errors)
    def write(self, data, eol = '\r', delay = 0.001):
        """
            Sends data to the serial port one character at a time to avoid MVME
            buffer overrun issues. Wraps the actual write function.
            
            Arguments:
                data (str): The data to send.
                eol (str): The end of line character to terminate the data with.
                delay (float): How long (in seconds) to wait between sending
                    successive characters.
                    
            No returns.
        """
        ## add the line end character to the string
        data = data + eol
        
        ## iterate through the string character by character
        for letter in list(data):
            ## send the character
            self.write_raw(letter)
            ## wait
            time.sleep(delay)
        
        ## log the string to the GUI
        self.gui.add_communication(str(data), 'tx')
                    
    ## write to the serial port. convert to bytes if not already
    def write_raw(self, data, is_bytes = False):
        """
            Converts data to bytes and writes it to the serial port.
            
            Arguments:
                data (str or bytes): Data to write.
                is_bytes (bool): True if the data is bytes, False otherwise.
                
            No returns.
        """
        ## convert to bytes
        if is_bytes == False and sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            data = bytes(data, encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore')

        try:
            ## write to the serial port
            self.connection.write(data)
            ## flush serial buffers
            self.connection.flush()
        except:
            ## complain about errors
            print('Serial write error')
            self.gui.add_communication('Serial write error!', 'error')

    ## read data from the receive queue
    def read(self):
        """
            Reads data from the receive queue.
            
            No arguments.
            
            Returns:
                (str) New data from the receive queue.
        """
        ## get data from the receive queue without blocking. if there is none,
        ## just return an empty string
        try:
            new_data = self.rx.get_nowait()
        except Queue.Empty:
            new_data = ''
            
        return new_data
        
    ## shut down the serial connection
    def kill(self):
        """
            Terminates the serial connection and serial thread (this thread).
            
            No arguments.
            
            No returns.
        """
        ## terminate the thread main loop
        self.terminate = True
        ## close the serial connection
        self.connection.close()
```

Unfortunately on the target PC, this code will cause a 'Visual C++ runtime error' stating that the program has requested termination in an unusual way. This occurrs when the first line of data is received from the serial device, or occasionally when the first line of data is sent to the serial device.

The serial port being used is in hardware (physical serial port on the machine). No flow control lines are used.

This leaves me a few questions:

- Why is this error occurring, or under what conditions could this error occur for other programs? Can you provide examples or references?
- Is it related to the self.gui.add_communication() call to update the GUI running in the main thread? If so, what mechanism can I use to pass these updates to the GUI, given that the main thread is blocked by mainloop() running on the Tk root?
- Can a pyserial write() call accept a string as data in this version of Python, rather than needing conversion to bytes as in Python 3?
- Why is no exception raised by Python before seeing the runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further invesigation this seems to be related to making calls to update GUI elements that were created in the main thread, rather than in this thread.

I have reimplemented GUI updates in this using queues, and have not seen the issue recur. The communication thread populates the queue, and the GUI thread uses the Tkinter event system to periodically poll this queue for updates.

The lesson here seems to be that you should only ever update GUI elements from the thread in which they were created.